# Writing chef test-kitchen integration tests for logstash filters

Tags: chef-infra, logstash, test-kitchen

There is a lot of ways to test logstash pipelines including:
1) Using logstash command line using config file
2) https://github.com/magnusbaeck/logstash-filter-verifier

The question is whether it's possible to integrate testing logstash filters (grok, mutate, date, etc) natively in chef test-kitchen using (ruby with serverspec or rspec).

Comment: are you asking "can it be done" (whether it's possible) or "how it can be done"?

Comment: would be great to have an answer for both or at least the first one.